# joining joints in corona using lua

Tags: lua

```
for i = 1,5 do    

local link = {}

for j = 1,20 do
    link[j] = display.newImage( "link.png" )
```

  -

---

1. List item

---

```
    link[j].x = 121 + (i*34)
    link[j].y = 55 + (j*17)
    physics.addBody( link[j], { density=2.0, friction=0, bounce=0 } )

    -- Create joints between links
    if (j > 1) then
        prevLink = link[j-1] -- each link is joined with the one above it
    else
        prevLink = beam -- top link is joined to overhanging beam
    end
    myJoints[#myJoints + 1] = physics.newJoint( "pivot", prevLink, link[j], 121 + (i*34), 46 + (j*17) )

end
end
```

What does this mean?
[image]

Comment: Please provide more details about what you need?

Comment: i mean i cannot understand the math part of it what does that 121+(i*34) mean where did 121 and 34 come from

Comment: this note could have been added to question. :) looks like someone already answered. I did not get a chance to work on `lua`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Corona SDK's manual](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/physicsJoints/index.html):

> A pivot joint, known as a revolute joint in Box2D terms, joins two
>   bodies at an overlapping point, like two boards joined by a rotating
>   peg. The initial arguments are bodies A and B to join, followed by the
>   x and y coordinates for the anchor point, declared in content space
>   coordinates.

```
local pivotJoint = physics.newJoint( "pivot", bodyA, bodyB, anchor_x, anchor_y )
```

So the values you ask about are anchor coordinates (the point where both bodies are linked)

The number values are just values someone picked to make it look like he wanted it to.

Just alter them and see the links move!

That's a general advice. If you don't know what something does, refer to the manual and if you cannot break anything (which is the case pretty much always) try what happens if you change it.
That's the only way you can understand things.